# How to make this image a border?

Tags: css

I'm making a pop-up box, and I have a custom border for it but I'm having trouble figuring out how to insert it into the code correctly.

**Here is the code for the box:**

```
.popup_block{
display: none; /*--hidden by default--*/
background: #ffffff;
float: left;
font-size: 1.2em;
position: fixed;
top: 50%; left: 50%;
z-index: 99999;
/*--CSS3 Box Shadows--*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
/*--CSS3 Rounded Corners--*/
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
img.btn_close {
float: right;
margin: -5px -5px 0 0;
}
/*--Making IE6 Understand Fixed Positioning--*/
*html #fade {
position: absolute;
}
*html .popup_block {
position: absolute;
}`

<div id="02" class="popup_block">

<Center> text goes here
</center></div>
```

**And here is the border:** [image: border]
Is there a way for me to place it on top of the pop up box or something? The inside is transparent so placing it overtop would work, I think. Unless there's an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use border-image and eventually position fixed from a wrapper.

```css
#poplayer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* might be usefull too
  z-index: XX;
  overflow:auto;  
  */
}
#popup {
  min-width: 450px;
  min-height: 150px;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 47px 34px 32px 39px; 
  -moz-border-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/a9ce6cf01114a325dcba725f18816a13/tumblr_oacf5xP6wh1vr8vsio1_1280.gif) 47 34 32 39 repeat; 
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/a9ce6cf01114a325dcba725f18816a13/tumblr_oacf5xP6wh1vr8vsio1_1280.gif) 47 34 32 39 repeat; 
  -o-border-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/a9ce6cf01114a325dcba725f18816a13/tumblr_oacf5xP6wh1vr8vsio1_1280.gif) 47 34 32 39 repeat;
  border-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/a9ce6cf01114a325dcba725f18816a13/tumblr_oacf5xP6wh1vr8vsio1_1280.gif) 47 34 32 39 fill repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="poplayer">
  <div id="popup">
    whatever comes inside your popup
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I didn't even have to create a wrapper, I just pasted those border-image codes below the ".popup_block" section of code. I filled in the border box with white in photoshop and made the background of the popup box itself transparent, removed the code for all the shadows & it worked like a charm. Took like 10 minutes to finish what I was trying to do for ages LOL. Border-image is how I initially tried to make this work but I'd gotten confused with the 4 values at the end & whether it should be repeating or stretched so I was thinking it couldn't be accomplished that way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping your popup box in a **`div`** tag and placing your custom border as a **`background-image`** for the parent **`div`**.

Make sure that your parent **`div`** has a small, all-around **`padding`** and that it is a bit larger, so that the popup box falls right in the whitespace.

You also have to **`position: absolute`** you popup box inside the parent and use something similar to the following CSS code:

```
.popup_block {
    /* Positioning */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
    /* Other styling properties */
}
```

In the code above, I use **`-40%`** instead of **`-50%`**, because you actually have to position it a little lower than the exact centre on y axis. You may need to play around and experiment with the exact number.

**Your HTML should be**:

```
<div class="popup_block-wrapper"> <!-- the parent -->
    <div id="02" class="popup_block">
        <center>text goes here</center>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS for the parent**:

```
.popup_block-wrapper {
    /* Positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* Other styling properties */
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I've never done this before so I appreciate the walkthrough. I tried inserting the new pieces of code but the only thing that changed is the pop up box got moved to the upper left. What did I do wrong? (editing, one sec)

Comment: `.popup_block-wrapper {
    /* Positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-image:url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/a9ce6cf01114a325dcba725f18816a13/tumblr_oacf5xP6wh1vr8vsio1_1280.gif);
    z-index: 99999;
}`

Comment: `.popup_block{
display: none; /*--hidden by default--*/
background: #ffffff;
float: left;
font-size: 1.2em;
position: absolute;
top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
z-index: 99999; ` 

 `<div class="popup_block-wrapper"> <!-- the parent -->
<div id="02" class="popup_block">
 
<Center>text here
</center></div></div> `

Comment: @taeyong can you make a jsfiddle with your code, HTML and CSS? It doesn't make much sense to me here in the comments. With your current code I don't see a visible result. In case you don'y know the website is: jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't see anything in the output. Did you try pressing run?

Comment: Yup, nothing happens when I press run?

Comment: When you press **`run`** the lower right window should show how your page. It currently shows nothing, which means that some of your code is missing.