# Can Linear Gradient be used as the color of the border of an image

Tags: css, image, border

Can we give linear-gradient as the border of an image??
something like this:

```
img {
    border: 10px solid linear-gradient(to right, red , blue);
}
```

If no what else can we do to achieve the same style.

Comment: yes, border-image or background + padding ;)

Comment: yes you can, you may refer to this guide - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-gradient-borders-pure-css

Comment: I got it!

img {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red , blue);
    padding: 10px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest would be a padding and a background:

```css
img {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200">
```

for a `border-image`, look at [How to make this image a border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407437/how-to-make-this-image-a-border/38408147#38408147) and this tool to help you sort it out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator

Comment: Yes, it worked really nice! Thank you so much